# Cluster analysis for ordinal temporal data

Tags: r, clustering, survey, ordinal-data

My objective is to cluster individuals according to their answers to a questionnaire. My data contains 10 variables across 20 quarters in 5 years. All variables are ordinal and take values from -5 to 5. Variables are the  individuals' answers to the questionnaire. Many variables have missing values: I have replaced them with 9's and with the medians (all methods are tested in both databases).

I have tried PAM (with Gower distance), Hierarchical clustering (Gower distance) and kmodes. In the first two cases, I ran the cluster analysis on the whole data base, regardless time variables. I ran it once and got 20 clusters per individual. I assigned the cluster which repeats the most (i.e., if individual A was assigned to 
cluster 1 1 time, to cluster 2--2 times, and to cluster 3--17  times, I assigned individual A to cluster 3).

I was wondering if my current approach is relevant to my objective. I am also wondering if I should take into consideration the time variable while performing clustering analysis.

Comment: have you considered other imputation methods for your missing data? seems like replacing the missing values with 9s will skew your distances, and replacing them with medians is as effective as removing that variable from clustering for that individual.  From cross sectional point of view assigning cluster by mode can be acceptable. From longitudinal perspective you need to consider transitions from one cluster to another

Comment: Replacing your missing values with 9s is a bad idea. Replacing them with the median is slightly less bad. A much better approach would be to use multiple imputation.

Comment: How is it that you got "20 clusters per individual" from, say, PAM? Are you saying that you ran PAM 20 times (with different settings somehow)? How are you identifying that something is "cluster A" from one run to the next?

Comment: I replaced them with 9s because I'm also interested on identifying which individuals did not ask a particular section. I ran kmodes asking for 3 clusters: 1 for the extreme values (9's ones) and 2 for the expected groups formed with individuals who answered every question. Although it will not be my final data base, I'm doing some practice in different data sets. I will take into consideration your opinions ragarding this aspect.

Comment: @gung I have 40 individuals and 20 quarters, so I have 800 rows and 10 columns (variables) . I used that data base in, say, kmeans function:  cluster <- kmodes(data[c(1:800),c(1:10)], 3)

Comment: would you mind rolling back to @gung's edit? As of now, your post is confusing